# Matlab path names with spaces... work around?

Tags: matlab

I have many folder names with spaces in it, ie "red dog" -->  "c:\red dog\"

```
files = dir
str = ['cd ', files(3).name]
eval(str)
```

The execution returns the error do to the space:

```
>> eval(str)
Error using cd
Too many input arguments.
```

---

What is the work around?... thx

Comment: Can you avoid using `eval` for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have a reason for using `eval`?  Try just

```
cd(files(3).name);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `cd(files(3).name)` instead of `cd files(3).name` (this is, call the `cd` function using brackets).

If for some reason you want to use `cd` as a command and not as a function (`cd myPath` instead of `cd(myPath)`), you have to enclose the string in single quotation marks. This way your example would look like this:

```
str = ['cd ''', files(3).name '''']
eval(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about matlab, but have you tried placing quotes around your file name?

```
files = dir
str = ['cd ''', files(3).name, '''']
eval(str)
```

Comment: FWIW, this would work if you used escaped single quotes `str = ['cd  '''  files(3).name, '''']`.  (Still not a good idea to use `eval` though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have RTW installed, you can use

```
cd( rtw_alt_pathname( files(3).name ) )
```

`rtw_alt_pathname` returns the path in 8.3 format